# Strange behaviour when calling an object more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code here that basically fades in and out some text from an array.

If I call it once, it works as intended. IE, it displays some text for 3 seconds and the fades in the next text from array.

If however I try to restart the animation again, it seems to run twice as fast. Can anyone help me? I think I can cancelling the previous animation correctly

In the code below, I call `rotator.start();` just to demo the problem I am having. Just call it once to see how it should behave.

http://jsfiddle.net/zmTAC/3/

```
<div id="foobar"></div>

<script>
    var rotator = {
        quoteIndex: -1,
        duration: 500,
        delay: 3000,
        play: false,
        quotes: [],
        theElement: null,

        start: function (quotes, theElement) {
            this.quoteIndex = -1;
            this.quotes = quotes;
            this.theElement = theElement;
            this.stop();
            this.play = true;
            this.showNextQuote();
            return this;
        },
        showNextQuote: function () {
            this.quoteIndex = (this.quoteIndex + 1) % this.quotes.length;
            if (this.play) {
                $(this.theElement).html(this.quotes[this.quoteIndex])
                    .fadeIn(this.duration)
                    .delay(this.delay)
                    .fadeOut(this.duration, this.showNextQuote.bind(this));
            }
            return this;
        },
        stop: function () {
            this.play = false;
            $(this.theElement).stop(true, true).show();
            return this;
        }
    };

    rotator.start(["foo1", "bar1"], "#foobar");
    rotator.start(["foo2", "bar2"], "#foobar");
    rotator.start(["foo3", "bar3"], "#foobar");
    rotator.start(["foo4", "bar4"], "#foobar");
    rotator.start(["foo5", "bar5"], "#foobar");
    rotator.start(["foo6", "bar6"], "#foobar");
    rotator.start(["foo7", "bar7"], "#foobar");
    rotator.start(["foo8", "bar9"], "#foobar");
    rotator.start(["foo9", "bar9"], "#foobar");
    rotator.start(["foo0", "bar0"], "#foobar");
</script>
```

Comment: it works fine in chrome.. is it browser specific??

Comment: Not for me. I've tried chrome. Look how the 2nd text that appears fades out quite quickly compared to the first

Comment: You can look into [Deferred Objects](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) Or Try [jQuery.when](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

Comment: What would I use them for? I'm trying to completely kill the previous animation before starting a new one

Comment: try to remove delay from your code.. it works smoothly. second animation is started before completion of first. so use when and done to run animation liner..

Comment: Sorry but I'm a little bit lost with how to implement your suggestions. Could you update my fiddle please?

Comment: I'm guessing jQuery uses setTimeout to do the animations, which creates asynchronous programming issues if multiple animations for the same element are queued.

Comment: I'm only seeing it fade in and out between `foo0` and `bar0`\

Comment: @Paul I assume the line $(this.theElement).stop(true, true).show(); would fix that :(

Comment: Need to separate constructing and running the full animation a bit more. Start does both and should be split.

Comment: Messing around with logging timing, it looks like the second item isn't being affected by delay. (the second `showNextQuote` is returning one second after the first one finishes, the first takes 3 seconds to return)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `$.stop()` is not cancelling the completed callback to `$.fadeOut()`.  I added a third element to the quotes array in the final call and every other quote was shorter (i.e. the second, then the first(in the second loop), then the third, etc.)

I'm not certain that is the cause (and if it is it is a bug in `$.stop()`) but a hack (but it works) is to create a container element which you compeltely remove in `rotator.stop()` and (re)create in `rotator.start()`.  Like this:

```
var rotator = {
        quoteIndex: -1,
        duration: 500,
        delay: 3000,
        play: false,
        quotes: [],
        theElement: null,

        start: function (quotes, theElement) {
            this.quoteIndex = -1;
            this.quotes = quotes;
            this.stop();
            this.theElement = theElement;
            $(this.theElement).html('<span class="rotator"/>');
            this.play = true;
            this.showNextQuote();
            return this;
        },
        showNextQuote: function () {

            if (this.play) {    
                this.quoteIndex = (this.quoteIndex + 1) % this.quotes.length;
                $('.rotator', this.theElement).html(this.quotes[this.quoteIndex])
                    .fadeIn(this.duration)
                    .delay(this.delay)
                .fadeOut(this.duration, this.showNextQuote.bind(this));
            }
            return this;
        },
        stop: function () {
            this.play = false;
            $('.rotator', this.theElement).stop(true, true).remove();
            $(this.theElement).show();
            return this;
        }
    };
```

See it working in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8HJtQ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

By calling `start` method you are overriding the quotes. It is playing between `foo0` and `bar0`. What you want to do is pass a single array of quotes like so:

```
rotator.start(["foo1", "bar1", "foo2", "bar2", "foo3", "bar3"], "#foobar");
```

Works fine on Firefox and IE for me. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zmTAC/6/) I also changed to jQuery 1.11.0 as 1.10 didn't work at all on IE.

**EDIT**

I am not sure what went wrong on jQuery side or on browser side. What I know you were doing a known mistake with the `this.play` variable. You set it to `false`, then to `true`, and then checked if it was `true` in the same function. If you run this function twice at the same time what you might get is:

```
this.stop(); // second execution is on this line
this.play = true; // first execution is on this line
this.showNextQuote();
```

What might happen is the second execution sets `this.play` to `false` and then the first execution sets it to `true`. What happens next in `showNextQuote` method is run by both executions as `this.play` is `true` for both (`showNextQuote` function checks if `this.play` is true).

I am not sure if it was the problem and I am pretty sure it was not the problem but what I showed you is what happens when you try to run multiple asynchronous operations. I am pretty sure it is buggy jQuery. Maybe newer version fixed this?

Maybe some other community member has more to say on this?

[Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/zmTAC/6/)

**EDIT2**

Thinking of it, JS would not allow it to happen as it would not execute this code in a separate threads. I wont delete it though as it explains you how easy it is to make this mistake with asynchronous jQuery that might be causing your problem.

Comment: I need to be able to override the quotes as they are generated dynamically by user input. I hardcoded them just to show the problem

Comment: Can you explain the changes you have made to get this to work, or explain what I was doing wrong?

Comment: Actually it doesn't make sense for me to have two methods, start() and setQuotes() as I won't be able to predict which one to call at the time of user interaction

Comment: @totalitarian Check my edit. You should call `start()` at the beggining of execution, then only user `setQuotes()`. You should make function `start()` not accept `quotes()` and use `setQuotes()` to actually set quotes. You have a couple of improvements to make in your code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50913/discussion-between-totalitarian-and-linek)

Answer (score 0):

can you try this instead of the commented line in your stop method

```
//$(this.theElement).stop(true, true).show();
$(this.theElement).finish().show();
```

working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kannetkeifer/9f6Ty/1/)